# how can i store a pointer to offseted location on malloced memory area in C?

Tags: c, pointers, lvalue

I'm trying to make a very simple Hashtable with libraries I got. The row that I try to make contains either C-string or int as key. Value can be of 4 different types. If it's struct I try to store a pointer in malloced memory area. However in my world this does not follow the same logic as non-pointer fields and I get:

```
error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value when I try to store pointer as value:
```

Here's the code

```
static void MakeRow(UtiHashtable_t *Hashtable, void *Key, void *Value, void *Row)
{
    int     KeySize, ValueSize;

    KeySize = sizeof(char) * Hashtable->KeyStringLength;
    ValueSize = GetValueSize(Hashtable);
    Row = malloc(KeySize + ValueSize);

    if (Hashtable->KeyType ==  MY_HASHTABLE_TYPE_STRING)  
        MyStrcpy((char *)Row, (char *)Key, Hashtable->KeyStringLength); 
    else if (Hashtable->KeyType ==  MY_HASHTABLE_TYPE_INT)
        ((int *)Row)[0] =  *(int *)Key;
    else
        MyAssert(0);

    switch (Hashtable->ValueType)
    {
    case MY_HASHTABLE_TYPE_STRING:
        MyStrcpy((char *)Row + KeySize, (char *)Value, Hashtable->ValueStringLength); 
        break;
    case MY_HASHTABLE_TYPE_INT: 
        *(int *)((char *)Row + KeySize) =  *(int *)Value;
        break;
    case MY_HASHTABLE_TYPE_DOUBLE: 
        *(double *)((char *)Row + KeySize) =  *(double *)Value;
        break;
    case MY_HASHTABLE_TYPE_STRUCT: 
        (int *)((char *)Row + KeySize) = (int *)Value;
        break;
    default:
        MyAssert(0);
    }
}
```

I know this is really basic and will get few down votes but besides the answer I would like to have explanation why this taking * away does not make it pointer.

The compiler allows:

```
(int *)Value = (int *)Key;
```

so why not:

```
(int *)((char *)Row + KeySize) = (int *)Value;
```

Thanks & BR -Matti

Comment: How do you come to the assertion that `(int *)Value = (int *)Key` would be valid? A cast always aplies to an expression and not to a variable and the result is always an rvalue.

Comment: @jens: compiler don't mind if Value's address is changed to Key's address.

Comment: this makes not much sense. Sure the compiler will "mind". You can't change addresses of variables, this is just what a variable is in C, a location in memory with a specific address.

Answer (score 1):

Using casts on an lvalue is deprecated.

Also, some systems don't allow `int`s or pointers  to be placed in arbitrary memory locations due to alignment issues.

What you should do is to `memcpy` the pointer value to where you want it.
And when you want to use the pointer you need to `memcpy` it back to a pointer variable.

Comment: thanks. anyway my Visual Studio 2010 C-compiler does not allow this. and I don't think this really works for structs (which is my case).

Comment: thanks! memcpy could be the answer. i'll get back to you when I'm done some testing.

Answer (score 0):

You left off the dereferencing * on the left side, so the assignment no longer makes any sense.

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand. there's not derefencing on either size. it's: (int *)((char *)Row + KeySize) = (int *)Value;

Comment: how can I dereference it if I want to store a pointer there? if I add * to head of left side it's naturally an other error: 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *'

Comment: try `*(int **)((char *)Row + KeySize) = (int *)Value`